# Reasons of laser power low frequency fluctuations

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser

I have fiber-coupled laser source - Thorlabs S1FC635, single-mode. I research the long-term instability of laser power. My experimental setup contains Thorlabs S1FC635,  single-mode fiber connected to collimator(F280APC-B). Laser beam is fixed by Si photodiode (S12915-1010R), signal from PD load transmitted to 24-bit DAQ system. I set laser power to 1mW.

So I recorded a lot of data and my question - what is the reason(s) of laser power fluctuations in APC mode? Their frequencies are about 0.277...0.555 mHz. My attempts to find the answer:

1)In ACC mode signals from external photodiode and internal photodiode (which in laser diode HL6320G, it in S1FC635...) almost similar so I think internal PD's parameters shouldn't change under the influence of self-heating laser diode + 1mW is small value...

2)Set-point value in laser driver is drifting but it more slower than 0.277...0.555 mHz and it doesn't repeat dynamic of "aforecited" fluctuations.

What I suppose:

1)Laser diode beam pointing drift -> amount of laser power entering to fiber is changes...

2)Fiber sense to low-frequency mechanical deformation

3)The amount of laser power falling to the internal photodiode changes (because LD resonator...) but why doesn’t the feedback system fix this?

I would be glad for any explanation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your second plot makes me suspect temperature changes in the lab and possible HVAC on/off oscillations. Just a guess.

Comment: Are you measuring in a noisy room? Do you by any chance have the system mounted on an optical table?

Comment: @JonCuster No, HVAC system is off in summer, and also I measure temperature near laser source (simultaneously with laser power in APC mode) , so you can see the plot of temperature data by link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GfGstjE3iVr-YlDtN8iRDSFupFAgmfo7/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @ondas In our lab we don't have sources of electromagnetic interference - only Wifi network router. There is no electric engines or very high voltage setups in lab, only computers, measurement electronics and optics. But there is a electric transformer substation near the lab. And yes, experimental setup is mounted on an optical table - is it gives mechanical influence to fiber?

Comment: I must say there is a perfect correlation between the temperature of your lab and the overall trend. The lab temp suddenly surges at 6h30 am. So do both graphs (in second, if you ignore the higher frequency oscillations. The second graph is obviously a 2 point control of something....quite typically something to do with thermals, what exactly I do not know. You should also pay attention to convection currents in the lab

Comment: Also, I do not understand your system. I checked the Thorlabs S1FC635 and I do not see any different operation modes or internal photo diode signal ports anywhere. I also find your question extremely hard to read/understand what you exactly mean (the English is not clear enough). Could you maybe rephrase your question and/or add more details? For example, I really cannot understand your point 1)

Comment: @U_K In my experience electromagnetic sources are not a huge problem but big electrical equipment are -- as far as a few rooms over. I worked with a smaller fiber laser for 6 years in several setups and I would see those fluctuations especially in a piezo sub-system. If you have any means to control the vibrations maybe take a look at that (piezo stages are good for those types of evaluations).

Comment: @JoséAndrade The S1FC635 has a jumper JMP1 that switches the operating modes (ACC or APC). To turn on laser in ACC mode, I moved the jumper to the appropriate position, then set the resistance of RP3 potentiometer to maximum (this is responsible for limiting the current) and removed the D3 diode.
In ACC mode, I also record the signal from photodiode amplifier (control point TP3, PDSET in PCB board) with  DAQ system. The 1st graph show signals from external  and internal photodiodes - before and after fiber...

Comment: @JoséAndrade This temperature data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GfGstjE3iVr-YlDtN8iRDSFupFAgmfo7/view?usp=drive_link is received with data in 2nd graph (APC mode). Also I measure temperature when laser was in ACC mode (in another day) - and there is a clear correlation between temperature and laser power, but there is no fluctuations with frequency 0.277...0.555 mHz ...
My main question - what is reasons of fluctuations with frequency 0.277...0.555 mHz when laser in APC mode?

Comment: @U_K Its from a control loop on some thermal effect: either a 2 point control or a PID. Thats why the frequency is higher when the slope of the temperature is also higher. I sincerely have no clue what ACC or APC mode mean. Also, the manual of the current version of the S1FC635 has no mention of those jumpers or modes of operation. Nonetheless, the amplitude of the total modulations is about 0.8% of the signal level (of course I do not know your background) and the oscillations of 0.2%. That sounds pretty darn good to me.

Comment: Also, how can you be sure that the big amplitude swing related to temperature do not actually come from the photodiodes heating up/cooling down? Because it really seems that as you start exposing the photodiodes it takes some time until they thermalize with the irradiated laser power.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thanks for the hint, it's interesting about the influence of the external thermal effect on the laser driver feedback system, I also thought about it. ACC is Automated Current Control and APC - Automated Power Control, you can read about it in laser driver's manuals or books. It is not written about this in the S1FC635's manual, but I deconstructed this laser source and recovered its electronic driver circuit, so my description of switching modes is unofficially.

Comment: @JoséAndrade As for the heating/cooling of photodiodes under the action of a laser beam, in the description I write that a laser power is about ~ 1mW, I think this is a small amount of laser power to heat the photodiode (S12915-1010R),  but as for the  internal photodiode (in laser diode) is the idea itself is good enough. Rather, after switching on, the laser source is self-heated and this affects the laser power.